# IE7: checkboxes don't scroll with containing li, display inappropriately

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I have a `<ul>` containing several vertically stacked `<li>`. The `<li>` scroll within the `<ul>`, and there are checkboxes contained within the `<li>`. In IE7, these checkboxes don't scroll with along with their containing `<li>`, and they show all the time even when they should be clipped. jsFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/m4asa/6/

Any ideas on what's causing this issue? The code works in Chrome, Firefox, and IE8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ul.selector li input[type="checkbox"] 
{
    display: block;
    left: 1px; top: 2px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    float: left;
}
```

Use that in your CSS instead of what you have for `ul.selector li input[type="checkbox"]`. You might have to adjust the margins a bit, but it fixes your scrolling issue for IE7 (tested in IE7 and Chrome, so you should check the other browsers to make sure it still works in those).

Comment: Though I think it should be position: relative and display: block.